# How to add Double tap to images in KivyMD?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

The double tap works on the first code that uses a .kv file however I don't know how to get it to work on a code that doesn't use a .kv file. The second code below is generating MDCards as posts with a title, image, and subtitle. I want to add double-tap to that image only. How can I achieve this?

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.behaviors import TouchBehavior
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton

KV = '''
Screen:
    MyButton:
        text: "PRESS ME"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
'''


class MyButton(MDRaisedButton, TouchBehavior):
    def on_double_tap(self, *args):
        print("<on_double_tap> event")


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


MainApp().run()
```

How can I add a double-tap to the image within the MDCard?

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivymd.uix.gridlayout import MDGridLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.behaviors import TouchBehavior
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from KivaMD.kivymd.utils.fitimage import FitImage

Window.size = (440, 760)

class MyButton(MDRaisedButton, TouchBehavior):
    def on_double_tap(self, *args):
        print("<on_double_tap> event")


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        blog = MDGridLayout(cols=1, spacing=40,  size_hint_y=None, padding=[20,], md_bg_color=[0,0,0.1,.2])
        blog.bind(minimum_height=blog.setter('height'))

        for i in range(10):
            post = MDCard(size_hint=(.9, None), size=(300, 300), radius=10)
            container = MDGridLayout(cols=1)
            post.add_widget(container)

            container.add_widget(MDLabel(text="Title", halign='center'))
            #ADD DOUBLE TAP TO THIS IMAGE
            container.add_widget(FitImage(source="data/assets/img/placeholder.jpg", size_hint_y=None, height=200))
            container.add_widget(MDLabel(text="Subtitle", halign='center'))

            blog.add_widget(post)
        scroll = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height))
        scroll.add_widget(blog)
        return scroll

MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it just as your show for the `MyButton` class:

```
class MyFitImage(FitImage, TouchBehavior):
    def on_double_tap(self, *args):
        print("MyFitImage: <on_double_tap> event")
```

Then use `MyFitImage` in place of `FitImage` in your code.